# To seek asylum from

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Say Marcia was born in the Kingdom of Liliput, a country with an oppressive government, and is a victim of persecution. She wants to leave her homeland and immigrate to the Kingdom of Blefuscu, seeking asylum. Would I say "Marcia seeks asylum from the Kingdom of Lilliput" or "Marcia seeks asylum from the Kingdom of Blefuscu"? On one hand, seeking something from another person means that you want something from them. On the other hand, having asylum from somebody means having protection from them. Is there a standard interpretation of this phrase, and if so, is there a standard wording of the other interpretation?

Comment: What research have you done?  What were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question.

The OED does not give examples of the single word *asylum* other than as a physical place, i.e. a sanctuary or inviolable place of refuge e.g. *lunatic asylum*.

It does not recognise *asylum* as a condition or status, except within the composite term ***political asylum***.

Of the three examples the OED gives for *political asylum*, only one is relevant to the question:

> 1991   Internat. Jrnl. Refugee Law 3 215   In a few exceptional cases,
>   Mexico has granted political asylum to persons who..applied for asylum
>   from outside the country.

This uses the preposition *to* in terms of granting *political asylum to*. Since *from* is the opposite of *to*, it therefore seems reasonable that **one seeks political asylum *from* the country one hopes will grant you refuge**.

But one seldom hears this used in news broadcasts etc. Mostly the talk is of someone being **granted/seeking asylum *in* a particular country**.

**So I would suggest the use of *in* or *from***. *Refugees in the jungle camp in Calais are wanting to claim political asylum **from/in** the United Kingdom*.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Google](https://www.google.co.th/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=asylum%20definition&oq=asylum%20definition&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.1552.4017.0.4240.18.11.0.7.7.0.134.1097.7j4.11.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..0.17.1060.0.7iVh9Kypt5s), asylum is the refuge granted by the nation one is fleeing to. So technically, she would be seeking asylum *from* the Kingdom of Blefuscu.

However, because it is quite vague, it would probably be better to say 'seeking asylum *in* the kingdom of Blefuscu' to avoid any possible confusion about the specific object / intended direction of the preposition *from* in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Then you should say : asylum **from** Blefuscu, ie. **in** Blefuscu ; or to get asylum **out** of Liliput, or **from outside** Liliput.